# fstream object is not reading data from the file?

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream student;
    student.open("details.txt");
    string name,UID,sem;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the name , UID , semester\n";
        cin>>name>>UID>>sem;
        student<<name<<" "<<UID<<" "<<sem<<endl;
    }
string xyz;


while(getline(student,xyz))    
{

    cout<<xyz<<"\n";
}





student.close();



}
```

This shows error but if i make ifstream object to write and ofstream object(which is different than object of ifstream) to read then only it is executed.
Thank you for helping me

Comment: `This shows error` what error does it show?

Comment: If you want to read from a file use ifstream, if you want to write to a file use ofstream. Using fstream just makes things more complicated.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default constructing them and immediately overwriting them. In this case, that means changing `fstream student; student.open("details.txt");` to `fstream student("details.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `student.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 0):

`<fstream>` contains `ofstream` and `ifstream` classes.

You should use `ofstream` object to write data to file:

```
ofstream fileOut("file-name.txt");
fileOut << "data";
fileOut.close();
```

and `ifstream` object to read data from file:

```
string data;
ifstream fileIn("file-name.txt");
fileIn >> data;
fileIn.close();
```

Comment: Ya if i write like this it will work but in which condition i can use fstream?

Comment: How to implement fstream in this program can you please help me to get this answer Thank you for help

Comment: You can use fstream, but you must specify how you would like to open the file (for reading or writing): 

fstream fs;
fs.open ("file.txt", std::fstream::in); // for reading;
fs.open ("file.txt", std::fstream::out); // for writing;
fs.close();